# How to run a Cardano relay instead of a full node?

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, cardano-node

I want to start a relay node not run the full cardano node.

There doesn't seem to be any tutorials for starting a relay node.

Anyone know how can i just a lightweight relay node so that I can run cardano-cli queries ?

Please note i only have 8 GB memory in docker so I can't afford to run a full node using docker or AWS/Google because they will cost a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relay is a full node. I thibk what you're asking is how can I have a light wallet like experience with cardano-cli and the answer to that is you can't; however you can use something like blockfrost API to get the same type of information cardano-cli can provide.

Comment: Oh i see :(, thanks for that, it's because i always run out of resources when trying to build a full node on docker.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says there is no real difference, a cardano-node is just configured to become a relay, its the same thing underneath.

If you build cardano-node from source, then you can control the number of threads used to compile with the standard -j flag, -j8 being 8 cores, more cores = more RAM needed.  https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/getting-started/install.md/

Still, actually running cardano-node on 8GB might be a bit too small, RAM optimizations are coming.